# Inplace editor for JSF2

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, facelets

I want to add Inplace editor to my web page. I searched the Internet but found nothing interesting. I've used primefaces inplace but the problem is that this plugin escape html. Does anyone know some jsf-2 component which can be used as inplace editor? Or should I write myself? Editor will be used for editing pages which contains html code.

Comment: Have you tried adding the parameter `escape=false`?

Comment: Yes I've tried. As far as I know Primefaces Inplace doesn't allow to unescape html.